# Append data to table row from pagination in Cakephp

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp

I have a simple data view using html table, my question is how do I can append the next data from pagination below the last row when I click the pagination link?

Comment: use datatables jquery plugin https://datatables.net

Comment: do you have any references? i need some samples to implement it...

Comment: its have full feature you can do whatever you want to do with it..

Comment: ya I know thanks for your idea, I mean is there any samples how to use datatables with cakephp pagination?

Comment: https://datatables.net/development/server-side/php_cake

Comment: https://github.com/cnizzdotcom/cakephp-datatable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved, i use the jquery ajax method to post last id from existing data and post it to other function called ajax_loadmore then i append the response to the existing table. it is simpler than i think...